# How can I create a dynamic object in a literal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an object which includes several fields, most values are strings (constants) but I also want to use a variable (populated using some state)

```
const {order} = this.state;

myObject={{
    fieldA: 2,
    fieldB: ${order.value}
}}
```

I tried different variation of the above (with/without single quotes, etc.) but I am never able to set the value I need.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a literal? What's wrong with `fieldB: order.value`?

Comment: Why don't you use simply the `fieldB: order.value`?

Comment: Do not need template literals for this

Comment: Please paste the entire code of the React Component you're working on so noone has to make any assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding 2 brackets for an object which is not valid and no need of template literal.

```
const { order } = this.state;

const myObject = {
  fieldA: 2,
  fieldB: order.value,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If `this.state` looks like this:

```
this.state = {order: ""}
```

Declaring

```
const {order} = this.state
```

would just create a constant called `order` that is holding the value of `this.state.order` at the time `order` was declared. It will **not** be updated when `this.state.order` is updated.

If you want to set myObject.fieldB to hold a reference to the value of `this.state.order`, that is, the state value of order, do this:

```
const myObject = {
  fieldA: 2,
  fieldB: this.state.order,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used two braces ('`{}`') which are not needed. The code should be like below

```
const myobject = {fieldA: 2, fieldB: order.value};
```